# OS X Native full on IDE

Tags: macos, text-editor, ide

I'm wondering if there is a good full on IDE for Mac. I know of and have tried Sublime, BBEdit, Coda, Espresso, Netbeans, Eclipse, Aptana, PHPStorm, WebStorm, Textmate and probably other that I don't remember.

What I mean by full on (which I believe excludes Sublime, BBEdit, Coda, Espresso and Textmate) is something like PHPStorm/NetBeans/Eclipse with a full feature set, intelligent code completion, code linking, etc.

I really like PHPStorm but it doesn't feel like a native OS X app and is really sluggish.

If anyone knows of IDE that I haven't mentioned above, would be much appreciated.

Comment: IDE for what lamguage? Also all the ones you mention are good - what functionality are they missing?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: PHP/JavaScript/CSS/Less. And yes, they're good in their own way. I like Sublime (lightning fast and lightweight) but lacks intelligent code completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Xcode can support web languages with some plugins, but all the informations I have are pretty old. http://web.archive.org/web/20110811093439/http://developer.apple.com/internet/scripting/phpappledevtools.html

And there are some projects to support autocomplete for PHP that I never really tried.
https://github.com/tonyjohnston/PHP-Xcode-Autocomplete

I'm very happy about PHPStorm, btw and I don't feel the need for a native IDE after moving to it from Eclipse/Aptana.

Comment: I do like PHPStorm a lot. Just feel its quite sluggish and not really native... Maybe its time to upgrade my Mac...

Comment: How old is your mac?

Comment: Its a MBP late 2008 (unibody, 2.53GHz Core 2 Duo, with a small SSD running from the ExpressCard slot, 512MB Video, 4GB RAM running Mavericks). I got the OS and apps running from the SSD and all data on a normal HDD. Mostly is ok but when I have many apps opened (which I do most of the time) as well as many tabs on Safari and Firefox/Chrome it does get very sluggish. Sometimes when I type, it doesn't show the text instantly. This doesn't happen all the time though.

Comment: Mmmm... It's starting getting older. Maybe a clean install could help :)

Comment: I've been thinking about it but I have been putting off the prospect of installing everything again... Alternatively I'm eyeing off the new Mac Pro. Maybe this will be the excuse my rational side needs... ;)